# How to close multiple windows working with Test NG framework

Tags: selenium, testing, junit, automated-tests, dataprovider

Suppose i have 5 test case and 2nd and 3rd one fails so after statement Assert.assertEquals("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/Managerhomepage.php",driver.getCurrentUrl());

driver.close will not work.
How to close all the windows failed once too

Trying with window handle too but not getting satisfactory results.

public static WebDriver driver;

```
@Test(dataProvider="inputdata")
public void login(String val1,String val2){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/rakesh/Desktop/chromedriver.exe");
    driver =new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys(val1);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(val2);
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
    Assert.assertEquals("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/Managerhomepage.php",driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.close();


}
@DataProvider(name="inputdata")
public Object[][] readExcel() throws BiffException, IOException {
    File f= new File("C:/Users/rakesh/Desktop/selenium/input data/loginTable.xls");
    Workbook w =Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
    Sheet s= w.getSheet("Sheet1");
    int rows=s.getRows();
    int columns=s.getColumns();
    //System.out.println(rows);
    //System.out.println(columns);

    String inputData [][] = new String[rows][columns];
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
            Cell c=s.getCell(j,i);
            inputData[i][j]=c.getContents();
            //System.out.println(inputData[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return inputData;


}
```

Comment: If you are opening new browser window with every test case, then it makes sense to close it at the end of that test case, whether your test case failed or passed.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use current `junit` version `4.12` and declare `@After` method which would execute after every `@Test` method -

> Method that is marked with @After gets executed after execution of
>   every test.

```
@After
public void closeConnection(){
    driver.close();
}
```

---

But then this would also *close the connection even if the test passes*. So to implement actions based on test results you can try using the [`TestWatcher`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) for Junit accordingly.